# How to get/create/impersonate InitiatorSession in AEM workflow

Tags: session, aem, sling, aem-6

In AEM workflow, When i try to impersonate workflowSession to initiator this throws exception :

> javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Impersonation not
>   allowed.

I necessarily need initiator's session to trigger some task in my workflow, earlier i used to get this using :

```
initiatorSession= adminSession.impersonate(new SimpleCredentials(initiatorUser,"".toCharArray()));
```

where adminSession is now deprecated and we use system users now, and so i cannot impersonate system user to initiator user, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a user account that has impersonation permission. Your service account needs to be an allowed impersonator for the user it is trying to impersonate.

Try to control permissions with appropriate user groups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your use case, but you should not impersonate the initiator if the workflow is now assigned to a **new user**. You can always adapt the `WorkflowSession` to a `Session`: `Session session = workflowSession.adaptTo(Session.class)` which will get you the initiators session unless the workflow went through a user step and changed to a new user. Otherwise you can create a system User session as you mentioned and use that.